# Counting non-isomorphic graph.

Tags: graph-theory

How many exists non-isomorphic 4-regular graphs $G = (V,E)$ where $|V|=7$ vertices?

I'm asking for hint to solve it with group theory( if it is possible) and without them

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** How many non-isomorphic $2$-regular graphs are there?

Comment: Can you elaborate? 2-regular graphs are sets of cycles enumerated by the partition function and two 2-regular graphs can be combined to make a four-regular graph but this only seems to work one way. The OEIS says this is apparently a challenging problem.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel The question asks for the number of nonisomorphic $4$-regular graphs on $7$ vertices. In that special case, the $4$-regular graphs are the complements of the $2$-regular graphs . . . oh, see dtldarek's answer!

Comment: (+1) $4+2 = 6 = 7-1$ I cannot believe I missed this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- How does a complement of such a graph looks like?
- How many such non-isomorphic complements exist?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$